# Spring Integration - delayer starts sending null message payloads when switched to using jdbcMessageStore and MySQL,works with H2

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl

I have the flow below which all worked fine until I added a messageStore to the delayer section (to get persistent messages).  This all worked with an embedded h2 database. If I then switch to a mysql database it doesn't work.

What happens now is that when the delayed message gets routed back to the submission channel by the pollOrTimeout flow, the message payload is null when it calls the handle function.

```
handle<Submission> { p, _ -> poll(p) }
```

This is odd as when I debug the code in the pollOrTimeout flow, the payload is populated.

Does anyone know why I'm getting this behaviour? I send a message at startup, or via the rest endpoint, it can take a couple of goes to replicate the error.

Error when running with mysql as the message store:

```
2022-05-19 15:32:43.684 DEBUG 46627 --- [   scheduling-1] o.s.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate               : Executing prepared SQL update
2022-05-19 15:32:43.684 DEBUG 46627 --- [   scheduling-1] o.s.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate               : Executing prepared SQL statement [DELETE from INT_MESSAGE where MESSAGE_ID=? and REGION=?]
2022-05-19 15:32:43.684 DEBUG 46627 --- [   scheduling-1] o.s.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils      : Fetching JDBC Connection from DataSource
2022-05-19 15:32:43.685 TRACE 46627 --- [   scheduling-1] o.s.jdbc.core.StatementCreatorUtils      : Setting SQL statement parameter value: column index 1, parameter value [581f4a27-a2b2-92ff-7741-5efdf1a0af73], value class [java.lang.String], SQL type unknown
2022-05-19 15:32:43.685 TRACE 46627 --- [   scheduling-1] o.s.jdbc.core.StatementCreatorUtils      : Setting SQL statement parameter value: column index 2, parameter value [DEFAULT], value class [java.lang.String], SQL type unknown
2022-05-19 15:32:43.689 TRACE 46627 --- [   scheduling-1] o.s.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate               : SQL update affected 1 rows
2022-05-19 15:32:43.689 DEBUG 46627 --- [   scheduling-1] o.s.i.jdbc.store.JdbcMessageStore        : Removing messages from group with group key=c54c4771-3f5d-3764-9d5f-f3c3c13d7451
2022-05-19 15:32:43.689 DEBUG 46627 --- [   scheduling-1] o.s.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate               : Executing SQL batch update [DELETE from INT_GROUP_TO_MESSAGE where GROUP_KEY=? and MESSAGE_ID=? and REGION=?] with a batch size of 100
2022-05-19 15:32:43.689 DEBUG 46627 --- [   scheduling-1] o.s.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate               : Executing prepared SQL statement [DELETE from INT_GROUP_TO_MESSAGE where GROUP_KEY=? and MESSAGE_ID=? and REGION=?]
2022-05-19 15:32:43.689 DEBUG 46627 --- [   scheduling-1] o.s.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils      : Fetching JDBC Connection from DataSource
2022-05-19 15:32:43.689 DEBUG 46627 --- [   scheduling-1] o.s.jdbc.support.JdbcUtils               : JDBC driver supports batch updates
2022-05-19 15:32:43.689 TRACE 46627 --- [   scheduling-1] o.s.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate               : Sending SQL batch update #1 with 1 items
2022-05-19 15:32:43.694 DEBUG 46627 --- [   scheduling-1] o.s.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate               : Executing SQL batch update [DELETE from INT_MESSAGE where MESSAGE_ID=? and REGION=?] with a batch size of 100
2022-05-19 15:32:43.694 DEBUG 46627 --- [   scheduling-1] o.s.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate               : Executing prepared SQL statement [DELETE from INT_MESSAGE where MESSAGE_ID=? and REGION=?]
2022-05-19 15:32:43.694 DEBUG 46627 --- [   scheduling-1] o.s.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils      : Fetching JDBC Connection from DataSource
2022-05-19 15:32:43.694 DEBUG 46627 --- [   scheduling-1] o.s.jdbc.support.JdbcUtils               : JDBC driver supports batch updates
2022-05-19 15:32:43.694 TRACE 46627 --- [   scheduling-1] o.s.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate               : Sending SQL batch update #1 with 1 items
2022-05-19 15:32:43.697 DEBUG 46627 --- [   scheduling-1] o.s.i.jdbc.store.JdbcMessageStore        : Updating MessageGroup: c54c4771-3f5d-3764-9d5f-f3c3c13d7451
2022-05-19 15:32:43.697 DEBUG 46627 --- [   scheduling-1] o.s.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate               : Executing prepared SQL update
2022-05-19 15:32:43.697 DEBUG 46627 --- [   scheduling-1] o.s.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate               : Executing prepared SQL statement [UPDATE INT_MESSAGE_GROUP set UPDATED_DATE=? where GROUP_KEY=? and REGION=?]
2022-05-19 15:32:43.697 DEBUG 46627 --- [   scheduling-1] o.s.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils      : Fetching JDBC Connection from DataSource
2022-05-19 15:32:43.697 TRACE 46627 --- [   scheduling-1] o.s.jdbc.core.StatementCreatorUtils      : Setting SQL statement parameter value: column index 1, parameter value [2022-05-19 15:32:43.697], value class [java.sql.Timestamp], SQL type unknown
2022-05-19 15:32:43.697 TRACE 46627 --- [   scheduling-1] o.s.jdbc.core.StatementCreatorUtils      : Setting SQL statement parameter value: column index 2, parameter value [c54c4771-3f5d-3764-9d5f-f3c3c13d7451], value class [java.lang.String], SQL type unknown
2022-05-19 15:32:43.697 TRACE 46627 --- [   scheduling-1] o.s.jdbc.core.StatementCreatorUtils      : Setting SQL statement parameter value: column index 3, parameter value [DEFAULT], value class [java.lang.String], SQL type unknown
2022-05-19 15:32:43.701 TRACE 46627 --- [   scheduling-1] o.s.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate               : SQL update affected 1 rows
2022-05-19 15:32:43.701 DEBUG 46627 --- [   scheduling-1] o.s.integration.channel.DirectChannel    : preSend on channel 'bean 'poll'; defined in: 'class path resource [com/example/springintegrationdemo/ChannelConfiguration.class]'; from source: 'com.example.springintegrationdemo.ChannelConfiguration.poll()'', message: GenericMessage [payload=Submission(submissionId=2, description=hello, delay=1000, status=NOT_READY), headers={replyChannel=nullChannel, pollCount=1, id=d2b60caa-1dd3-f38e-02ff-688ab279b38c, timestamp=1652970762671}]
2022-05-19 15:32:43.701 DEBUG 46627 --- [   scheduling-1] o.s.i.router.MethodInvokingRouter        : bean 'pollOrTimeOut.router#0' for component 'pollOrTimeOut.org.springframework.integration.config.ConsumerEndpointFactoryBean#0'; defined in: 'class path resource [com/example/springintegrationdemo/SubmissionConfiguration.class]'; from source: 'bean method pollOrTimeOut' received message: GenericMessage [payload=Submission(submissionId=2, description=hello, delay=1000, status=NOT_READY), headers={replyChannel=nullChannel, pollCount=1, id=d2b60caa-1dd3-f38e-02ff-688ab279b38c, timestamp=1652970762671}]
2022-05-19 15:32:43.701 TRACE 46627 --- [   scheduling-1] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'submissions'
2022-05-19 15:32:43.702 DEBUG 46627 --- [   scheduling-1] o.s.integration.channel.DirectChannel    : preSend on channel 'bean 'submissions'; defined in: 'class path resource [com/example/springintegrationdemo/ChannelConfiguration.class]'; from source: 'com.example.springintegrationdemo.ChannelConfiguration.submissions()'', message: GenericMessage [payload=Submission(submissionId=2, description=hello, delay=1000, status=NOT_READY), headers={replyChannel=nullChannel, pollCount=1, id=d2b60caa-1dd3-f38e-02ff-688ab279b38c, timestamp=1652970762671}]
2022-05-19 15:32:43.702 DEBUG 46627 --- [   scheduling-1] o.s.i.t.MessageTransformingHandler       : bean 'submissionFlow.header-enricher#1' for component 'submissionFlow.org.springframework.integration.config.ConsumerEndpointFactoryBean#0'; defined in: 'class path resource [com/example/springintegrationdemo/SubmissionConfiguration.class]'; from source: 'bean method submissionFlow' received message: GenericMessage [payload=Submission(submissionId=2, description=hello, delay=1000, status=NOT_READY), headers={replyChannel=nullChannel, pollCount=1, id=d2b60caa-1dd3-f38e-02ff-688ab279b38c, timestamp=1652970762671}]
2022-05-19 15:32:43.702 DEBUG 46627 --- [   scheduling-1] o.s.integration.channel.DirectChannel    : preSend on channel 'bean 'submissionFlow.channel#0'; defined in: 'class path resource [com/example/springintegrationdemo/SubmissionConfiguration.class]'; from source: 'bean method submissionFlow'', message: GenericMessage [payload=Submission(submissionId=2, description=hello, delay=1000, status=NOT_READY), headers={replyChannel=nullChannel, pollCount=1, id=d2b60caa-1dd3-f38e-02ff-688ab279b38c, timestamp=1652970762671}]
2022-05-19 15:32:43.702 DEBUG 46627 --- [   scheduling-1] o.s.i.handler.ServiceActivatingHandler   : ServiceActivator for [org.springframework.integration.handler.LambdaMessageProcessor@aa1b4da] (submissionFlow.org.springframework.integration.config.ConsumerEndpointFactoryBean#1) received message: GenericMessage [payload=Submission(submissionId=2, description=hello, delay=1000, status=NOT_READY), headers={replyChannel=nullChannel, pollCount=1, id=d2b60caa-1dd3-f38e-02ff-688ab279b38c, timestamp=1652970762671}]
2022-05-19 15:32:43.702 DEBUG 46627 --- [   scheduling-1] o.s.integration.handler.DelayHandler     : Release flow threw an exception for message: GenericMessage [payload=org.springframework.integration.handler.DelayHandler$DelayedMessageWrapper@f90e37f0, headers={replyChannel=nullChannel, pollCount=1, id=581f4a27-a2b2-92ff-7741-5efdf1a0af73, timestamp=1652970762671}]

org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandlingException: error occurred in message handler [ServiceActivator for [org.springframework.integration.handler.LambdaMessageProcessor@aa1b4da] (submissionFlow.org.springframework.integration.config.ConsumerEndpointFactoryBean#1)]; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException: Parameter specified as non-null is null: method com.example.springintegrationdemo.SubmissionConfiguration.poll, parameter input
    at org.springframework.integration.support.utils.IntegrationUtils.wrapInHandlingExceptionIfNecessary(IntegrationUtils.java:191) ~[spring-integration-core-5.5.11.jar:5.5.11]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:65) ~[spring-integration-core-5.5.11.jar:5.5.11]
```

Main code here:

```
package com.example.springintegrationdemo

import org.springframework.boot.ApplicationRunner
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication
import org.springframework.boot.runApplication
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration
import org.springframework.integration.annotation.MessagingGateway
import org.springframework.integration.channel.DirectChannel
import org.springframework.integration.dsl.MessageChannels
import org.springframework.integration.dsl.StandardIntegrationFlow
import org.springframework.integration.dsl.integrationFlow
import org.springframework.integration.jdbc.store.JdbcMessageStore
import org.springframework.integration.jdbc.store.channel.ChannelMessageStoreQueryProvider
import org.springframework.integration.jdbc.store.channel.MySqlChannelMessageStoreQueryProvider
import org.springframework.integration.store.MessageGroupStore
import org.springframework.messaging.Message
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController
import java.io.Serializable
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger
import javax.sql.DataSource


data class Submission(val submissionId: String,val description : String, val delay : Long, val status : String) : Serializable


@SpringBootApplication
class SpringIntegrationDemoApplication {

    @MessagingGateway(defaultRequestChannel = "submissions")
    interface SubmissionGateway {
        fun poll(submission: Submission)
    }

    @Bean
    fun jdbcChannelMessageStore(dataSource: DataSource): JdbcMessageStore {
        return JdbcMessageStore(dataSource)
    }

    @Bean
    fun queryProvider(): ChannelMessageStoreQueryProvider = MySqlChannelMessageStoreQueryProvider()


    @Bean
    fun runner(gateway: SubmissionGateway): ApplicationRunner? {
        return ApplicationRunner {
          gateway.poll(Submission("mySubmissionId", "my submission", 1000L, ""))
        }
    }
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    runApplication<SpringIntegrationDemoApplication>(*args)
}

@Configuration
class ChannelConfiguration {

    @Bean
    fun submissions(): DirectChannel = MessageChannels.direct().get()

    @Bean
    fun ready(): DirectChannel = MessageChannels.direct().get()

    @Bean
    fun notReady(): DirectChannel = MessageChannels.direct().get()

    @Bean
    fun poll(): DirectChannel = MessageChannels.direct().get()

    @Bean
    fun timeout(): DirectChannel = MessageChannels.direct().get()
}



@Configuration
class SubmissionConfiguration(val channels: ChannelConfiguration) {

    val notReady = "NOT_READY"
    val ready = "READY"
    private val pollCount = "pollCount"

    @Bean
    fun submissionFlow(): StandardIntegrationFlow = integrationFlow(channels.submissions()) {

        enrichHeaders {
            headerFunction<Any>(pollCount) {
                AtomicInteger()
            }
        }
        handle<Submission> { p, _ -> poll(p) }

        route<Message<Submission>> {
            when (it.payload.status) {
                ready -> channels.ready()
                else -> channels.notReady()
            }
        }
    }


    fun poll(input: Submission): Submission {
        val status = if ((0..10).random() == 0) ready else notReady
        println("in polling input is $input, result is $status")

        return input.copy(status = status)
    }


    @Bean
    fun readyFlow(): StandardIntegrationFlow = integrationFlow(channels.ready()) {
        handle {
            println("Handling ready message $it")
        }
    }

    @Bean
    fun notReadyFlow(messageStore: MessageGroupStore): StandardIntegrationFlow = integrationFlow(channels.notReady()) {

        delay("delayer.messageGroupId") {
            messageStore(messageStore)
            delayFunction<Submission> {
                it.headers[pollCount, AtomicInteger::class.java]?.getAndIncrement()
                println(it.headers[pollCount])
                it.payload.delay
            }
        }

        channel("poll")
    }

    @Bean
    fun pollOrTimeOut(): StandardIntegrationFlow = integrationFlow(channels.poll()) {

        route<Message<*>, String>({
            val count = it.headers[pollCount].toString().toInt()
            if (count > 10) {
                "timeout"
            } else {
                "submissions"
            }

        }
        ) {


        }
    }


    @Bean
    fun timeoutFlow(): StandardIntegrationFlow = integrationFlow(channels.timeout()) {
        handle {
            println("Handling timeout message $it")
        }
    }
}


@RestController
class SubmissionController(val submissionGateway: SpringIntegrationDemoApplication.SubmissionGateway) {

    @PostMapping("/")
    fun save(@RequestBody subMission: Submission) {
        return submissionGateway.poll(subMission)
    }
}
```

resources/schema.sql:

```
CREATE TABLE INT_MESSAGE  (
                              MESSAGE_ID CHAR(36) NOT NULL,
                              REGION VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
                              CREATED_DATE TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
                              MESSAGE_BYTES LONGVARBINARY,
                              constraint INT_MESSAGE_PK primary key (MESSAGE_ID, REGION)
);

CREATE INDEX INT_MESSAGE_IX1 ON INT_MESSAGE (CREATED_DATE);

CREATE TABLE INT_GROUP_TO_MESSAGE  (
                                       GROUP_KEY CHAR(36) NOT NULL,
                                       MESSAGE_ID CHAR(36) NOT NULL,
                                       REGION VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
                                       constraint INT_GROUP_TO_MESSAGE_PK primary key (GROUP_KEY, MESSAGE_ID, REGION)
);

CREATE TABLE INT_MESSAGE_GROUP  (
                                    GROUP_KEY CHAR(36) NOT NULL,
                                    REGION VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
                                    CONDITION VARCHAR(255),
                                    COMPLETE BIGINT,
                                    LAST_RELEASED_SEQUENCE BIGINT,
                                    CREATED_DATE TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
                                    UPDATED_DATE TIMESTAMP DEFAULT NULL,
                                    constraint INT_MESSAGE_GROUP_PK primary key (GROUP_KEY, REGION)
);

CREATE TABLE INT_LOCK  (
                           LOCK_KEY CHAR(36) NOT NULL,
                           REGION VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
                           CLIENT_ID CHAR(36),
                           CREATED_DATE TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
                           constraint INT_LOCK_PK primary key (LOCK_KEY, REGION)
);

CREATE SEQUENCE INT_MESSAGE_SEQ START WITH 1 INCREMENT BY 1;

CREATE TABLE INT_CHANNEL_MESSAGE (
                                     MESSAGE_ID CHAR(36) NOT NULL,
                                     GROUP_KEY CHAR(36) NOT NULL,
                                     CREATED_DATE BIGINT NOT NULL,
                                     MESSAGE_PRIORITY BIGINT,
                                     MESSAGE_SEQUENCE BIGINT NOT NULL ,
                                     MESSAGE_BYTES LONGVARBINARY,
                                     REGION VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
                                     constraint INT_CHANNEL_MESSAGE_PK primary key (REGION, GROUP_KEY, CREATED_DATE, MESSAGE_SEQUENCE)
);

CREATE INDEX INT_CHANNEL_MSG_DELETE_IDX ON INT_CHANNEL_MESSAGE (REGION, GROUP_KEY, MESSAGE_ID);
-- This is only needed if the message group store property 'priorityEnabled' is true
-- CREATE UNIQUE INDEX INT_CHANNEL_MSG_PRIORITY_IDX ON INT_CHANNEL_MESSAGE (REGION, GROUP_KEY, MESSAGE_PRIORITY DESC, CREATED_DATE, MESSAGE_SEQUENCE);


CREATE TABLE INT_METADATA_STORE  (
                                     METADATA_KEY VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
                                     METADATA_VALUE VARCHAR(4000),
                                     REGION VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
                                     constraint INT_METADATA_STORE_PK primary key (METADATA_KEY, REGION)
);
```

build.gradle.kts:

```
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile

plugins {
    id("org.springframework.boot") version "2.6.7"
    id("io.spring.dependency-management") version "1.0.11.RELEASE"
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.6.21"
    kotlin("plugin.spring") version "1.6.21"
    kotlin("plugin.serialization") version "1.6.21"
    java
}

group = "com.example"
version = "0.0.1-SNAPSHOT"
java.sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_11

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    listOf("integration","webflux","data-jpa","web").forEach {
        implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-$it")
    }

    implementation("org.springframework.integration:spring-integration-jdbc")
    implementation("com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin")
    implementation("io.projectreactor.kotlin:reactor-kotlin-extensions")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-serialization-json:1.3.2")
    runtimeOnly("com.h2database:h2")
    developmentOnly("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools")
    testImplementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test")
    testImplementation("org.springframework.integration:spring-integration-test")
}

tasks.withType<KotlinCompile> {
    kotlinOptions {
        freeCompilerArgs = listOf("-Xjsr305=strict")
        jvmTarget = "11"
    }
}

tasks.withType<Test> {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

Comment: As you can see in the log, the payload is clearly not `null` - `GenericMessage [payload=Submission(...`. Must be some Kotlin weirdness - not sure how the DB type can influence that.

Comment: Interesting... Any chances that you can share a project with us to reproduce and play with? Do you do some custom (de)serialization for messages to/from the store? I see that you use `LONGVARBINARY`, not `BLOB` for message content....

Comment: Perhaps deserialzied `Submission` comes from different `ClassLoader`, then that `handle<Submission>` expectations, so that `args[i] = this.messageConverter.fromMessage(message, this.expectedType);` returns null, just because it cannot cast one `Submission` to another for the reason of their different class loaders....

Comment: Thanks 

I'll post a project in GITHUB with a mysql and h2 branch. I'll also change the submission to be a Java POJO just to exclude the Kotlin deserialisation angle.

I just used the scripts that are contained within the spring-integaron-jdbc jar, so haven't changed any BLOBS etc.

Comment: Well, you did. Here is how that script looks in the project: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/blob/5.5.x/spring-integration-jdbc/src/main/resources/org/springframework/integration/jdbc/schema-mysql.sql#L5

Comment: Consider to inject a `DefaultDeserializer` into that `JdbcMessageStore`, but supply it with the beans `ClassLoader`: `@Bean fun messageDeserializer(beanFactory: ConfigurableBeanFactory) = DefaultDeserializer(beanFactory.beanClassLoader)`

Comment: Yes, my post was a bit confusing in that the script posted was for the h2 database. Sorry about that.

Artem - your comment about the class loader was the clue - it was Spring Dev Tools that caused the issue. As soon as I removed that it worked. Oddly it doesn't seem to affect it on h2. I can still upload the project if you want to see the behaviour ?

Answer (score 1):

This was caused by having the spring dev tools dependency. Thanks to Artem and Gary for the clues in the comments that pointed me in the right direction.

```
 developmentOnly("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools")
```

I've uploaded a sample project that replicates the issue. Follow the instructions in the README.md to replicate.

https://github.com/frayneposset/springintegratondemo

To fix the problem, simply remove the above dependency.

Alternative fix is to use a custom deserializer like so:

```
@Bean
    fun jdbcChannelMessageStore(dataSource: DataSource,beanFactory: ConfigurableBeanFactory): JdbcMessageStore {
        val jdbcMessageStore = JdbcMessageStore(dataSource)
        val deserializer = DefaultDeserializer(beanFactory.beanClassLoader)


        jdbcMessageStore.setDeserializer {
            deserializer.deserialize(it) as Message<*>
        }
        return jdbcMessageStore
    }
```

Comment: That's good. But would you mind to confirm how that works with an explicit `DefaultDeserializer` based on the beans `ClassLoader`? I mean I consider this as a bug in the framework, but for the proper path I need more confirmations. Thank you!

Comment: Yes, that fixes it. I've updated the repo and will change my answer to show the fix.

Comment: Great! I will prepare some out-of-the-box fix shortly then!

Comment: Here is the fix: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/pull/3809